# Compact subset of compactly generated group

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group, that is also Hausdorff and second countable.  Let $S$ be a compact subset that generates $G$ as a group, which contains the identity and is closed under taking inverses.  Let $T$ be any compact subset of $G$.  Is it true that $T \subseteq S^k$ for some $k$?

What if the assumption of second countability is dropped?

Comment: Yes, it is true. See Proposition 2.C.3 of the following book:

Comment: A metric panorama of locally compact groups, by Yves de Cornulier and Pierre de la Harpe. It is available online.

Comment: @Vahid: that's perfect, thanks!